# c++ DLL\static library name issue

Tags: c++, dll, static-libraries

I have problem that I am completely dumbfounded by and am hopping someone can point me in the right direction.

I have a DLL which has a static library linked in.  In the DLL I have a function with the following signature and beginning:

```
CellMatrix BasisSwapFlows(double spread, const std::string & convention, int startDate, int endDate, bool forceEOM, const CellMatrix & returnSide, bool explode)
    CashFlow::Vector flows(basisSwapFlows(spread, getBasisSwapConvention(convention), XLDate(startDate), XLDate(endDate), forceEOM));
    ....
```

In there I call a function from the static library with the signature:

```
CashFlow::Vector basisSwapFlows(double spread, const BasisSwapConvention & convention, const XLDate & startDate, const XLDate & endDate, bool forceEOM)
```

When I compile and run this in release mode then during the call to the static lib, the first parameter (spread) seems to be uninitilized.  However, at the call site (in the DLL) it clearly is.  This does not happen in Debug Mode.  Also, if before the call to the static lib I make a copy of the argument i.e.:

```
double spread_loc(spread);
CashFlow::Vector flows(basisSwapFlows(spread_loc, getBasisSwapConvention(convention), XLDate(startDate), XLDate(endDate), forceEOM));
    ....
```

and pass that, the problem does not occur.  Finally, if I modify the name of the static lib function to say basisSwapFlows_v2 the problem again goes away.  However, reordering the parameters does nothing.

I'm using the VS2010 C++ compiler.  Please let me know if there is any other info I can provide.

Edit: I also discovered that this problem goes away when I turn off optimization in the release build in both libraries.  In fact, just disabling optimization in the DLL makes the problem go away.

Edit 2:  Also discovered that just turning off Whole Program Optimization but leaving each project of Full Optimization resolves the problem.

Edit 3: Leaving all optimization on but taking the parameter by const ref also fixes the problem.

Comment: I work with Stas. I went through all the optimization options, and all that needs to be turned off in order for it to work normally is Whole Program Optimization. Every other optimization can be left in place.

Answer (score 1):

This very well could be an issue of using different versions of the stl.  When you use runtime c++ libraries it is crucial that the same compiler with the same options was used in the client and linked library.  Is it possible that you are calling the debug version of the library with the release version of the client or visa versea

Comment: I don't think so.  I was under the impression that you would get a iterator debug level mismatch error in that case.  Also, I'm building both libraries my self.  This is not third party software.

Answer (score 0):

The DLL and the static library must be compiled under the same conditions, that is memory alignment (byte, word, long), calling conentions (which is probably satisfied here) and same type lengthes (for example `int` might take 4 bytes on one compiler/switches and 2 bytes on another).

Comment: I am the one building both libraries and I did not change the compiler conditions (Not those any way).